# No puedo leer fichero de objetos en Java

Tags: java

Mi problema es con el `ObjectOutputStream`, solamente me funciona cuando escribo un objeto la primera vez. Si a ese archivo le vuelvo a añadir un objeto me lanza la siguiente Excepción:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1596)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
at Ejemplo.leer(Ejemplo.java:62)
at Ejemplo.main(Ejemplo.java:17)
```

A continuación les enseño el código de como estoy guardando y recuperando los objetos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Alumno alu = new Alumno("29521268D", "Pepe García");
    Alumno alu2 = new Alumno("23456789L", "Jose Ramón");
      escribir(alu, "alumnos_prueba.dat");
    //escribir(alu2, "alumnos_prueba.dat");

    leer("alumnos_prueba.dat");


}

public static <T> void escribir(T objeto,String nombre_archivo){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(nombre_archivo,true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objeto);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos!=null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> void leer(String nombre_archivo) {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream(nombre_archivo);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        T objeto;
        while(fis.available()>0) {
            objeto = (T)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(objeto);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

La clase Alumno tiene implementada la interfaz serializable y puesto un serialVersionUID

```
public class Alumno implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String dni;
private String nombre;

public Alumno(String dni, String nombre) {
    this.setNombre(nombre);
    this.setDni(dni);
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "DNI: "+this.getDni()+" Nombre: "+this.getNombre();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se escribe un fichero con objetos se escribe una cabecera al inicio. Si escribes una vez e intentas leer no habrá fallo. El programa ve la cabecera y leerá todo perfectamente. Si intentas añadir algo nuevo al fichero escribirá después de lo ya existente una nueva cabecera. Cuando intentes leer usará la primera cabecera y leerá el primer valor, pero cuando intentes leer el segundo, escrito con otra cabecera, lanzará un error por cabecera corrupta. La documentación sobre ese error en el método [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

la solución a este problema es, que cada vez que quieras escribir algo nuevo crees un nuevo lo primero que hay que hacer es crear un canal de lectura y de escritura e ir leyendo y escribiendo todo (sin cerrar el canal de escritura) y cuando llegues al final escribir lo nuevo y entonces cerrar los canales.

Si quieres mantener el fichero con objetos, cada vez que quieras escribir un objeto nuevo, vas a tener que crearte un fichero nuevo, copiar todos los objetos que hubiera y escribir los nuevos sin cerrar el canal de escritura.

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto a ver si te funciona

```
public static <T> void escribir(T objeto,String nombre_archivo){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(nombre_archivo,true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objeto);
        oos.flush();
        oos.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos!=null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```